# css for particular table's rows and columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have many html tables and one of these are  named as "table1". I want to give style to this table only. 
I used:

```
#table1 tr,th,td
  {

   border: 5px solid black;
  }
```

But when it executed, other table's `td , tr, th` style is setted same as `#table1` 's style.

How Can I give Style to particular table's `td , tr, th` only????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the parent also for `th` and `td`

```css
#table1 tr, #table1 th, #table1 td {
    /* ... */
}
```

otherwise you will apply that style to

- `#table1 tr` (all `tr` inside `#table1`)
- `th` (all `th` no matter where they are)
- `td` (all `td` no matter where they are)

As a side note, on certain modern browser a `:any` pseudoclass [is available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aany) (with `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes) so as soon as it will be implemented more consistently you could write

```css
#table1 :any(tr, th, td) {
   ...
}
```

useful to avoid the repetition.